# Performance issue with Frameless

Tags: framerjs

I am facing severe lagging problems while running my Framer prototype on Frameless. I'm using iPhone 5c. I've cleared all the applications and the WiFi transfer rate seems fine. But still the prototype is not working fine in Frameless. It runs smoothly on Framer Studio. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it. It has to do with how heavy your imports are from Sketch/Photoshop. After removing some unnecessary imports, Frameless is working as smooth as Framer Studio. That said, I don't think you can prototype a "screen-heavy" app completely in Framer. I think it's better to break them into modules and work on each screen interaction separately. I hope the Framer guys bring in some more performance to the app.